# How to find which radio Button is selected after a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I find which radio button is selected after a precise div?

This is an Example:

```
<div class="largelines">
    <p class="line">OPTION 1</p>
    <div class="delete">
        <a href="#" title="Delete"></a>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" value="option1"><label for="option1">option1 </label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="option2" name="option2" value="option2"><label for="option2">option2 </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here, when I click on the class .delete I would like to check (with jQuery) if one of the radio button below (inside the fieldset) has been selected. Do you have any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is just bunch of radio button you would like to check are checked or not you can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').on('click', function(){
        $(document).find('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
            if($(this).get(0).checked){
                //do something
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Ofc in line 3 you can specify more about the radio button location. For exp `$(document).find('.largelines input[type=radio]')` "OR" if you need to find radio butons based on delete button you can modify the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').on('click', function(){
        var $parent = $(this).parents('.largelines');
        $parent.find('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
            if($(this).get(0).checked){
                //do something
            }
        });
    });
});
```

There is bunch of other ways to do that, another one is using `next()` or `siblings()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').on('click', function(){
        var $fieldset= $(this).next('fieldset');
        //var $fieldset= $(this).siblings('fieldset');// i comment this out [its alternative way]
        $fieldset.find('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
            if($(this).get(0).checked){
                //do something
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: There are different bunches of buttons, so I need to check the one inside the next fieldset

Comment: @db92 i added more details about your issue

Answer (score 0):

This find only checked radio under `.largelines` scope of clicked `.delete` element.

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var isChecked = $('input:radio:checked', $(this).parent()).length > 0
    alert(isChecked)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="largelines">
    <p class="line">OPTION 1</p>
    <div class="delete">
        <a href="#" title="Delete">Check 1</a>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1" value="option1"><label for="option1">option1 </label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="option2" name="option2" value="option2"><label for="option2">option2 </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="largelines">
    <p class="line">OPTION 2</p>
    <div class="delete">
        <a href="#" title="Delete">Check 2</a>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" id="option21" name="option1" value="option1"><label for="option1">option1 </label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="option22" name="option2" value="option2"><label for="option2">option2 </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```